# WPF DataGrid - SelectedItem not changing on FullRow selection outside text

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm building a Datagrid that has rows with height=40. On a row selection, the program opens a new tab with a User Control specific to that item.

When I click anywhere in the row that's outside of the cell contents ([Red boxes in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIREc.png)), The event fires but 'CurrentItem' does not get updated.

Essentially, the row only gets selected if the cell contents are clicked. Has anyone else dealt with this, and have a solution for what's going on?

Here's my styling:

```
        <DataGrid Name="MachinesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MainData.Machines}">
        <DataGrid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
                <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow" />
                <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushBackground}" />
                <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="{StaticResource BrushGreyMid}" />
                <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="{StaticResource BrushGreyDark}" />
                <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None" />
                <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushBlue}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushWhite}" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="CellStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushWhite}" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="RowStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushGreyLite}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushBlue}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know your problem is that selection is initially triggered in `DataGridCell`, by setting

```
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
```

your are telling that `DataGridCell` should vertically centered within a `DataGridRow` which leads to some space top and bottom which is not part of the `DataGridCell` and therefore not triggering any selection.

To solve this you have to set `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`(default) but then your content isn't centered anymore, for this you have to override the `ControlTemplate` of `DataGridCell`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now you can set `VerticalContentAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` on `DataGridCell` to align your content.

---

Your `DataGridCell`-Style should then look like this

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushWhite}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```